# Scraping json data using vba

Tags: vba, json, web-scraping

I've created a scraper using vba which is able to parse json response. When I was thinking of using scripting dictionary or json converter to scrape json data I could notice that applying split function on responsetext is fairly easy to get the expected outcome. It is working great now. I've written like this:

```
Sub Json_coder()
Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, itm As Variant
    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", False
        .send
        itm = Split(.responseText, "id"":")
    End With
    x = UBound(itm)

    For y = 1 To x
        Cells(y, 1) = Split(Split(itm(y), "name"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 2) = Split(Split(itm(y), "username"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 3) = Split(Split(itm(y), "email"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 4) = Split(Split(itm(y), "street"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 5) = Split(Split(itm(y), "suite"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 6) = Split(Split(itm(y), "city"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 7) = Split(Split(itm(y), "zipcode"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 8) = Split(Split(itm(y), "phone"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 9) = Split(Split(itm(y), "website"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 10) = Split(Split(Split(itm(y), "company"": ")(1), "name"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 11) = Split(Split(itm(y), "catchPhrase"": """)(1), """")(0)
        Cells(y, 12) = Split(Split(itm(y), "bs"": """)(1), """")(0)
    Next y
End Sub
```